# Using Google API ServiceAccountCredential in WinRT application

Tags: c#, google-api, windows-runtime, google-drive-api

I wanted to create a "report a problem" tool for my WinRT (Windows 8.1) application, and use my Google Drive to store screenshots of the reported problems.

Unfortunately, I'm having issues making any progress when it comes to using the Google API in my app.

The first hurdle is authentication. I've added the Nugget package Google.Apis.Drive.v2 and created a service account.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find the `ServiceAccountCredential` class. It SHOULD be in `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2`, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case. The only thing that I have access to is the `ServiceAccount` base class (which I cannot use) and the `UserAccount` class, which isn't what I'm looking for.

I'm stumped. Is it a case of attempting to use the Google API in a non-mobile Windows 8.1 application? Or is there something else that's wrong?

I could really use a WinRT example of an app using the service-account to access any of the Google APIs - a working example would likely make a lot of things instantly clear.

Answer (score -1):

There's a helpful [documentation with samples from Google](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) about the .NET APIs Library,
In this one, it describe how to authenticate your request:

```
var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secrets.json"),
    new[] { Uri.EscapeUriString(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar) },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None);
var calendarService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Windows 8.1 Calendar sample"
    });
var calendarListResource = await calendarService.CalendarList.List().ExecuteAsync();
```

[Windows 8.1 Apps Auth](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#windows-81-applications)

Comment: The example you give is for regular client access, which requires authentication on part of the user. The point is to use a service account and NOT require the user to enter any credentials.